# angularFileUpload and $http

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing my first AngularJS app, and I have a problem.
The problem is that I need to use $http to send POST data, and I need too use angularFileUpload from https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload, and when I code

```
angular.module('WishList', ['angularFileUpload']).controller('MainControl',['$scope','FileUploader',$http,function($scope,FileUploader,$http){/*Code*/}]);
```

Doesn't work.
I've looked for the solution, but I have not find it.
What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: You forget the quotes around `$http`.

Comment: With quotes, I have another problem `Error: [$interpolate:interr]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by doesn't work. But you're missing quotes around the $http dependency declaration

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I've used quotes sorrounding $http, and now I have this problem in navigator Error: [$interpolate:interr]
`angular .module('WishList', ['angularFileUpload']).controller('MainControl', ['$scope', 'FileUploader','$http', function($scope, FileUploader,$http) {`

Comment: an interpolation error is usually something wrong with the markup. Do you have the rest of the error?

Comment: yes, of course, i put part of code, and full message error:

`Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Buploader%7D%7D&p1=TypeError%3A%20Converting%20circular%20structure%20to%20JSON
    at Error (native)
    at http://test.com/WishList/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Function.Ka.interr `

Comment: `(http://test.com/WishList/lib/angular/angular.min.js:192:129)
    at u (http://test.com/WishList/lib/angular/angular.min.js:93:465)
    at http://test.com/WishList/lib/angular/angular.min.js:117:394
    at Object.get (http://test.com/WishList/lib/angular/angular.min.js:116:17)
    at n.$digest (http://test.com/WishList/lib/angular/angular.min.js:132:124)
    at n.$apply (http://test.com/WishList/lib/angular/angular.min.js:135:269)
    at l (http://test.com/WishList/lib/angular/angular.min.js:87:152)
    at F (http://test.com/WishList/lib/angular/angular.min.js:91:187)`

Comment: Its impossible to say without seeing the code, but I'd guess you have a scope variable you're trying to display that has a circular reference in it e.g. `$scope.myvar = {'foo': 'bar'};  $scope.myvar.somethingElse = $scope.myvar;` and angular internally is trying to convert $scope.myvar to Json to display it. Try going through the variables that you're trying to display to see whether any of them reference themselves (possibly indirectly)

Comment: @jjczopek  I'd agree it should have been a comment, but I don't have the reps to comment on anything other than my own answers

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote to github's repository of the lib developer, and they've told me that it is not possible to mix $http and FileUploader...